# Update 'additional_attributes' for a single product

Tags: magento-enterprise, attributes, api, php-5.4

I'm trying to update a single 'additional_attribute' for a product.  The documentation on this is sparse and I've tried to piece it together via info from the web and browsing the code in Magento, but I can't seem to get it right.  Here's the code I have right now:

```
$update_data = array (
    'additional_attributes' => array (
        'single_data' => array (
            'warehouse' => '6'
        )
    )
);
$update = $proxy->catalogProductUpdate($sessionId, 'MySKU', $update_data);
```

All the configurations of the $update_data array that I've tried throw an error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Cannot access empty property in /var/www/localhost/docs/magentoapi/update_test.php:38
```

Line 38 is:

```
$update = $proxy->catalogProductUpdate($sessionId, 'MySKU', $update_data);
```

Running Magento EE 1.14.0.1.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was finally able to figure this out.  Working code:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient("https://www.mysite.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl");
$sessionId = $proxy->login("apiuser", "apipass");

// $prodinfo->set will give you the attribute set of the product
// for *MY* product, this results to '13' which is used in the next step
$prodinfo = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, 'MYSKU');

// $attribinfo[xxx]->code will give you the name of the attribute
// $attribinfo[xxx]->attribute_id will be the id of said attribute
// 'xxx' being an array key
// for *MY* product, the attribute I want to update is 'warehouse'
$attribinfo = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeList($sessionId, '13');

// $attribvalues[xxx]->label is the name of the attribute value
// $attribvalues[xxx]->value is the id of the attribute value
// you will use the *ID* to update your product
// for *MY* product, this id is '5'
$attribvalues = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeOptions($sessionId, 'warehouse');

// multiple additional attributes can be added as new elements to the
// 'single_data' array
$update_data = array (
    'additional_attributes' => array (
        'single_data' => array (
            array ('key' => 'warehouse', 'value' => '5')
        )
    )
);

// and the update call
$update = $proxy->catalogProductUpdate($sessionId, 'MYSKU', $update_data);
```

Hope this helps someone else.